# Paste grouped values into SQL query structure from data frame with single quotations in R

Tags: sql, r, dataframe, for-loop, dplyr

Ok so I'm trying to take a dataframe with the following structure:

```
df <- data.frame (name  = c("name_1", "name_2", "name_3", "name_4", "name_5"),
                  groups = c("group_1","group_1","group_2","group_2","group_3"),
                  values = c(1234, 2345, 3456, 6789, 7890))
```

And ready it for insertion into a SQL query.

The output I'd like to be (for insertion into a SQL query):

```
( (values IN ('1234', '2345') AND UPPER(groups) = 'GROUP_1') 
OR (values IN ('3456','6789') AND UPPER(groups) = 'GROUP_2') 
OR (values IN ('7890') AND UPPER(groups) = 'GROUP_3') )
```

I had this set up with a for-loop but I need it to be entirely dplyr or some form of base R or tidyverse. The real data frame is much larger than this so it needs to be a dynamic/scalable solution.

Here are a few things I've begun to try that haven't done the trick so far:

1st step:

```
zoop <- df %>% group_by(groups) %>%  summarize(values2 = toString(unique(values)))
```

Which is the same as:

```
aggregate(values2 ~ groups, data = zoop, paste, collapse = ",")
```

Doesnt work as it pastes all values for all groups despite grouping:

```
df %>% group_by(groups) %>%  summarize(newcol = paste0(sprintf("'%s'", unique(df$values)), collapse = ", "))
```

2nd step:

doesnt work as I need to separate this into chunks for each group:

```
df %>% group_by(groups) %>%  summarize(values2= toString(unique(values))) %>% summarise_all(funs(paste(na.omit(.), collapse = ",")))
```

What I had used before in the for-loop was:

```
# Find groupings
new_groups <- df%>% group_by(groups) %>% summarise(n_distinct(groups)) %>% select(-"n_distinct(groups)")

# set up blank df to hold group/value combos per grouping
value_group_combo <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol=1, nrow=0)),c("STRINGS") )

# Make a string of group/value combos for each group for the query
for(i in 1:nrow(new_groups)){
  
  group <- new_groups[[i,c("groups")]]
  
  # Get all values for the selected group, string into one string with commas and single quotes
  value_list <- df %>% filter(groups == group) %>% select(values) %>% unique()
  value_list <- paste0(sprintf("'%s'", value_list$values), collapse = ", ")
  
  value_string_base <-  " (values IN (<VALUESTRING>) AND UPPER(groups) = '<GROUPTYPE>') OR"
  
  value_group_string <- gsub("<VALUESTRING>", value_list, 
                             value_string_base)
  value_group_string <- gsub("<GROUPTYPE>", group, 
                             value_group_string)
  
  if(i == nrow(new_groups)){
    # Chop off LAST 'OR'
    value_group_string <- substring(value_group_string, 1, nchar(value_group_string)-2)
    
  }
  
  # keep running list of strings for query
  value_group_combo[i, "STRINGS"] <- value_group_string
  
} # end of group loop

# Collapse all value/group combos for query substitution
group_value <- paste0(sprintf("%s", value_group_combo$STRINGS), collapse = "")
```

Maybe somehow using apply? Not sure.

Thank you!

**EDIT**: I used ChatGPT to give an alternative and it worked well:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame (name  = c("name_1", "name_2", "name_3", "name_4", "name_5"),
                  groups = c("group_1","group_1","group_2","group_2","group_3"),
                  values = c(1234, 2345, 3456, 6789, 7890))

query_parts <- df %>% 
  group_by(groups) %>% 
  summarise(values2 = paste0("('", paste(unique(values), collapse = "','"), "')"), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  mutate(query_string = sprintf("(values IN %s AND UPPER(groups) = '%s')", values2, toupper(groups)))

final_query <- paste(query_parts$query_string, collapse = " OR ")

print(final_query)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a dplyr solution

```
df %>% 
  group_by(groups) %>%  
  summarize(values2 = glue::glue_collapse(glue::single_quote(unique(values)), ", ")) %>% 
  mutate(cmd=glue::glue("(values IN ({values2}) AND UPPER(groups) = '{groups}')")) %>% 
  pull(cmd) %>% 
  glue::glue_collapse(" OR ") %>% 
  paste0("( ", . ," )")

# "( (values IN ('1234', '2345') AND UPPER(groups) = 'group_1') 
# OR (values IN ('3456', '6789') AND UPPER(groups) = 'group_2') 
# OR (values IN ('7890') AND UPPER(groups) = 'group_3') )"
```

We use `glue` to help with the string building but you could easily replace that with `paste` if you want.